# getting usable values from statsmodels WLS

Tags: python, regression, linear-regression, statsmodels, weighted

I'm using statsmodels' weighted least squares regression, but getting some really huge values.

Here's my code:

```
X = np.array([[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[4,5,6],[1,2,3]])
y = np.array([1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1])
w = np.array([0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5])

temp_g = sm.WLS(y, X, w).fit()
```

Now, what I understand is that in WLS regression, just like in any linear regression problem, we provide the endog vector and the exog vector and the function can find the line of the best fit and tell us what the coefficients/regression parameters for each observation ought to be. For example, in my data, where each observation consists of 3 features, I'm expecting there to be 3 parameters.

So I fetch them like this:

```
parameters = temp_g.params # I'm hoping I've got this right! Or do I need to use "fittedvalues" instead?
```

The issue is that I'm getting really huge values like this:

```
temp g params : 
[ -7.66645036e+198  -9.01935337e+197   5.86257969e+198]
```

or this:

```
temp g params : 
[-2.77777778 -0.44444444  1.88888889]
```

Which is creating problems in further usage of these parameters, especially since I have some exponents to work with as well, and I need to raise `e` to the power of some of the regression parameters, which is proving impossible, given such big numbers. Because I keep getting overflow errors when using `exp()`.

Is this normal? Am I doing something wrong? Or is there a specific way to make them useful?

Comment: The estimated parameters aren't huge; they are zero (e-323). Also, it is just a symptom of the problem. Your X matrix is just bad; do a summary of your model: `temp_g.summary()`. You should get at least some kind of warning about your data (e.g., 'singular matrix')

Comment: Sorry I'd pasted the wrong values, I've edited the question to repaste the values I'm getting. Anyway, I tried as you said and yes I am getting warnings. I wanted to test the algorithm on a small dataset but I guess this is too small. I'll try again with other data.

Comment: It's not about the size of the data; the fundamental problem is how your X matrix columns are related to each other: the correlation between the columns is 1.

Comment: For example, if you do that regression in stata, stata will automatically drop one of your columns to make the regression work. statsmodels didn't automatically try to make the regression work, it just gave a warning telling you there are problems.